# Python mock return value

Tags: python, mocking

Normally, when using mock, I'll have

```
from mock import Mock

m = Mock()
m
<Mock id='4334328720'>
```

Is it possible to change this output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. You can inherit from Mock and change the `__repr__` method:

```
from mock import Mock
class Mock2(Mock):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Hello World!"

m = Mock2()

>> m
Hello World!
```

You could also dynamically change the `__repr__` method of your object like this:

```
from mock import Mock
m = Mock()

def new_repr(self):
    return "Hello dynamic Python!"
m.__repr__ = new_repr

>> m
Hello dynamic Python!
```